# Can UPDI Enabled AVRs be Programmed at 1.8V?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, avr, programming

Microchip's new line of Tiny AVRs use the new UPDI programming interface.

After looking at the datasheets for the [ATtiny817](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001901B.pdf)/[1617](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001893B.pdf), the [Atmel ICE interface document](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42330-Atmel-ICE_UserGuide.pdf), and the internet, it's still unclear whether these new devices can be programmed/debugged @ 1.8V.

Has anyone attempted 1.8V UPDI programming/debugging, and did it work out of the box?

Comment: Microchip have started making AVRs? <blink>

Comment: 'Tis true.  The real question for me is: will the plethora of peripherals found on their PIC16 line make their way in the ATtiny.  I'm particularly fond of the peripheral pin selection (any peripheral to any pin) and the OpAmp+Comparators.